# Java spring framework: application context won't set properties

Tags: java, html, spring, inheritance

The problem:

the content div does not show the image string (set in the application context in an object of receipt) when i run it in chrome.

The ItemGroup class has a list of Items
and Receipt is a Subclass of the abstract class Item

this is my code in netbeans:

applicationContext.xml:

```
 <bean id="receipt1" class="domain.receipts.Receipt" >
        <property name="id" value="1"/>
        <property name="image" value="Images/receipt.png"/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="receipts" class="domain.ItemGroup">
        <property name="items">
            <list>
                <ref bean="receipt1"/>        
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="image" value="/Images/klantenkaart.png"/>
 </bean>
```

HomeController:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController 
{
private ItemGroupService itemGroupService;

@Autowired
private ItemGroup receipts;
@Autowired
private ItemGroup shoppinglists;
@Autowired
private ItemGroup cards;

@Autowired
public HomeController(ItemGroupService ItemGroupServiceImpl)
{
this.itemGroupService=ItemGroupServiceImpl;
}


public List<Item> getReceipts()
{
    return receipts.getItems();
}

@RequestMapping(value = {"/index"},method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showHomePage(Model model) 
{
model.addAttribute("itemGroup", new ItemGroup());
return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = {"/index"},method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String onSubmit(@ModelAttribute("itemGroup") ItemGroup itemGroup, Model model)
{

    if(itemGroup.getName().equals("receipts"))
    {
       model.addAttribute("itemList",receipts.getItems());
    }
    else if(itemGroup.getName().equals("cards"))
    {
       model.addAttribute("itemList",cards.getItems());
    }
    return "index";
    }
 }
```

index.jsp

```
<div id="header">
  <table>
      <tr>
   <form:form method="POST" action="index.htm" modelAttribute="itemGroup">
     <form:input path="name" type="hidden" value="receipts" /> 
     <input type="image" src="Images/receipt.png" height="150px" width="180px" alt="Submit" value="receipts">    
   </form:form>
   <form:form method="POST" action="index.htm" modelAttribute="itemGroup">     
     <form:input path="name" type="hidden" value="shoppinglists" /> 
     <input type="image" src="Images/shoppinglist.png" height="150px" width="180px" alt="Submit" value="shoppinglists">
   </form:form> 
   <form:form method="POST" action="index.htm" modelAttribute="itemGroup">     
     <form:input path="name" type="hidden" value="cards" /> 
     <input type="image" src="Images/loyalitycard.png" height="150px" width="180px" alt="Submit" value="cards">
  </form:form> 
   <form:form method="POST" action="index.htm" modelAttribute="itemGroup">     
     <form:input path="name" type="hidden" value="vouchers" /> 
     <input type="image" src="Images/voucher.png" height="150px" width="180px" alt="Submit" value="vouchers">
  </form:form> 
     </tr>
  </table>

</div>

<div id="leftcol">
    </br>
</div>

<div id="content">
      </br>
      <h1> ${itemList}</h1>     
           <c:forEach items="${itemList}" var="prod" >
                <h1>${prod.image}<h1>            
           </c:forEach>   
</div>
```

Item class:

```
public abstract class Item 
{
    private int id;
    private String barcode;
    private Date creationDate;
    protected String image;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBarcode() {
        return barcode;
    }

    public void setBarcode(String barcode) {
        this.barcode = barcode;
    }

    public Date getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
```

Comment: Did you debug the controller to verify the parameter is being correctly put into the model? That'll at least help you narrow down whether the application context is to blame or the model/jsp.

Comment: yeah but it's hard to tell

Answer (score 0):

```
 model.addAttribute("itemList",cards.getItems());
```

debug this piece May be find something!